# Pytrends anaconda install conflict with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

It seems I have a conflict when trying to install pytrends via anaconda. After submitting "pip install pytrends" the following error arises:

tensorflow-tensorboard 1.5.1 has requirement bleach==1.5.0, but you'll have bleach 2.0.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-tensorboard 1.5.1 has requirement html5lib==0.9999999, but you'll have html5lib 0.999999999 which is incompatible.

I also have tensorflow but don't necessarily need it. But I'd prefer a means to operate with both.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your version of tensorflow. I tried it with Tensorflow 1.6.0 ,tensorboard 1.5.1 and it worked fine. I was able to import pytrends.